# Installing nginx through Powershell in Amazon EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, powershell, windows-10

I have an Amazon EC2 instance. I want to install nginx web server on it. I have established a connection in Powershell(Windows 10) to the server.
[PowerShell screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfw63.png)
I have searched but haven't found an answer. I know it can be done easily in Linux but i want to do it in Windows. Is there a way to do so?

Tried installing Chocolaty too but Looks like Chocolaty as a PowerShell Repository Source is not available on EC2 instance machine. The instance is a Windows Server 2016 Data Center edition Nano. I can feel that something very small is missing but can't make out what.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running nano server you will not be able to use the official Nginx release as it is a 32 bit application and Nano server will only run 64 bit applications.

There are other third party, 64 bit builds of Nginx but I do not have experience with them.

Comment: There is currently nothing on that server. If I can terminate that and start a new full build, will I be able to install nginx through Windows Package Control on that instance?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you use Core rather then Nano you should be able to install Nginx normally.

Comment: Much thanks. Looks like nano was the problem. I'm now using Windows Server 2016 with Containers ami and connecting via RDP(instead of PowerShell as in the case of nano). Everything is working so well.